# cURL for Amazon product image url works only in localhost

Tags: php, curl

I have gotten a cURL script to work so that it gets the image of a product from Amazon, but it only works on localhost, on my website it doesn't work.

Please can someone help me get it working?

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    return @curl_exec($ch);
}

$html=getHTML("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003B7Q5YY",10);

    preg_match_all('/,"large":"(.*?)",/', $html, $output);
        foreach ($output[1] as $key=>$value) {

        echo $value;

    }
```

Comment: whats [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) show?

Comment: It doesn't show any errors, it just shows a blank page. But in localhost work perfect.

Comment: remove the `@` and do `echo $html;`, whats that show? does your host have curl?

Comment: I have removed the @ and I have put echo $ html; and now it shows the full Amazon page, but only on localhost, on my website it still shows a blank page. It seems that Amazon blocks it to only work on locahost, but there must be some way to make it work.

Comment: check console in network tab is it 200 or 500? if its 500 check your server logs (curl might not be installed). maybe try echoing something so you know its not dead and/or enable some [error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), if your blocked curl_error would have yielded something like connection refused..

Comment: though after all is said and done it could be blocked, which might be likely if your on a shared host which 100's of its customers are doing scrappy things

Comment: Returns 200. cURL is installed, I have it running on my website to get product images from other online stores, and it works fine. Only on Amazon it doesn't work. I'm going to try to get some kind of error, although I'm a bit clumsy with php and curl.

Comment: Start by removing the `@` before your `curl_exec()` call and enable error reporting by setting `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and see if you get a descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure so you have curl installed and enabled

```
if (function_exists('curl_version')) {
  // CURL is installed and enabled.
}
```

Installing the curl extension can be done like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

You will need change the package name `php7.3-curl` to match you php version.

Depending on how you are running php you might need to restart your web server or the php fpm service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service php7.3-fpm restart
```

When I tried this locally I noticed that the response was gzipped and therefore I needed to set the `Accept-Encoding` header using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```

Comment: That response is a 503, which could be very relevant if that's what OP is receiving.

Comment: True that, I totally missed the actual response code =) But anyway it works fine for me setting the CURLOPT_ENCODING option, without it I just get a gzipped response and the preg match obviously fails.

Comment: @msbit just tracked this down, the reson why we get a 503 is most probably because curl is blocked as a user-agent so setting this to something else fixes this.

Comment: For instance `curl -s -o /dev/null -D - -H "User-agent: whatever" https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003B7Q5YY -H "Accept: */*"`, notice that if you let curl set the `User-agent` header to its default e.g `curl -s -o /dev/null -D - https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003B7Q5YY -H "Accept: */*"` then you'll get a 503. I have seen this behavior before.

Comment: It also doesn't work with gzip enabled, I had already tried it. Amazon rejects the connection. It only works on localhost

Comment: So what http response code to you receive? Can paste the entire response from curl? If you have access it would be nice if you could ssh into the remote server and try to just do a curl from there and give me the output e.g `curl -s -o /dev/null -D - -H "User-agent: whatever" https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003B7Q5YY`

Comment: Hi Clyconecode, I have uploaded a screenshot, so you can see all the answer: https://pasteboard.co/Jp6mwCj.png

Comment: It returns a 200 response, the same as the browser, but in the browser it does not show anything, it shows a blank page, although as I mentioned before ... in localhost it returns the answer correctly.

Comment: Do you have an URL where I can test this script and see the response for myself?